# running code in the event-loop from blockingHandler in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

In my app the server registar to network which notify callback when there's new info.
The network registarion blocking so that I run this code with blockHandler.
The problem is that the registration require callback as param and I want to run the callback in the event loop. how can I do it?
the network code can't be change.

```
vertex.executeBlocking(event->{
      network.registart(new CallBack(){
            public void newData(Data d)
            {
                  runThisCodeInEventLoop(); // I want to run this code in the event loop.
                  event.complete(); 
            }
      },false,ev->{
             ....some code...
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `registart` method is blocking? It seems non-blocking since it needs a callback.

Comment: Maybe just run it in result handler?

Comment: The data arrival comes by callback and non-blocking but the register to the network is blocking since it takes some second to connect. about result handler - can you explain?

Comment: Result handler - is where "....some code..." written - it's executes in event loop thread when future completes.

Answer (score 0):

All verticles run in the event loop unless told otherwise.
If you need to execute some code on the event loop, spin a verticle, and communicate with it using EventBus:

```
 public void newData(Data d)
            {
                  // This will go back to the event loop
                  vertx.eventBus().publish("channel", "something");
                  event.complete(); 
            }
```

And your "event loop verticle":

```
class WorkerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("channel", (o) -> {
            // Do something smart here
        });
    }
}
```

If you also need to receive something from the event loop, use `send()` instead of `publish()`

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_event_bus_api